# Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tb_perumahan' in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, where-clause

So I want to make a website that selling houses, but when I tried to join two tables with a filter but it came to this error...

I've tried to swap the tables but it still error.

```php
$this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tb_rumah');
      $this->db->join('tb_perumahan', 'tb_perumahan.id_perumahan = tb_rumah.id_perumahan');
      $perumahan = $this->db->get_where('tb_perumahan', ['id_perumahan' => $id_rumah])->row_array();
```

So, can anyone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `get_where()` method after a `join()`, you are selecting from the same table twice, and using the same name for each, which I suppose you're not intend to.
Try to change the `get_where()` method to `where()` and change it's parameters :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tb_rumah');
$this->db->join('tb_perumahan', 'tb_perumahan.id_perumahan = tb_rumah.id_perumahan');
$perumahan = $this->db->where('tb_perumahan.id_perumahan', $id_rumah)->row_array();
```

Comment: don't you need a `get()` somewhere in the above code in order to access the result object? e.g. `->where(...)->get()->row_arrray()`

Comment: Alex is right, this will produce error without the `get()` method before `row_array()`